# How can I extract tracking ID and Courier name from text message received from that company using java?

Tags: java, android, text-analysis

I have text messages in my inbox,i want to select the messages which are from any courier company and extract tracking Id and Courier company name from that message using java code for Android application

Comment: Sounds great. So what's your question exactly?

Comment: @yole I have described the question,pls let me know what's not clear.Thanks.

Comment: First, your question doesn't contain any code, so it's not possible to say which exactly part of the task presents a problem to you, or whether you just expect people on the Internet to write some code for you. Second, we have no idea what messages from your courier company look like.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is some SMS template being used and I considered below one.

***"Dear Customer, your courier with  AWB no:1234567 will be delivered by ABC couriers. For any queries..."***

So for that, you extract values using Java's String class methods `substring()` & `indexOf()`.

Example for you:

```
String message = "Dear Customer, your courier with  AWB no:1234567 will be delivered by ABC couriers. For any queries...";
String awb = message.substring(message.indexOf(":")+1, message.indexOf("will")-1);
String comp = message.substring(message.indexOf("by")+2 , message.indexOf("Couriers")-1);
```

Modify the code accordingly.